# How to define globally a user input as variable

Tags: common-lisp

Is there a way, in common lisp, to receive a user input, say `"foo"`, and `defvar` a global variable `*foo*`?

For example (which does NOT work):

```
(defun global-name (s)
  "Takes s and changes it to *s*"
  (concatenate 'string "*" s "*"))

(defun add-global-var (var)
  "defvars a global variable and adds it to *global-list*"
  (let ((var-name (global-name var)))
    (defvar var-name var)
    (push var-name *global-list*)))

; Used like this:
(add-global-var "myvar")
```

In this case, the `var-name` is a `string`, and will not work with `defvar`.

Comment: Are you sure you really need to do this? You probably should convert the variable name to uppercase.

Comment: Ah, yeah, the upper case problem. I missed that. Thank you. I am investigating the power of the language. I don't have a need to do this.

Comment: If you do not have a need to do it, you are investigating something other than the power of the language. That said, try writing a macro that expands to `(defvar *myvar* ...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Déjà vu... I asked these kinds of questions 20+ years ago ;-)

## Your question

Yes, you can do that (but **no**, you do ***not*** want to!)

```
(defun add-global-var (var-name &optional (package *package*))
  (let ((var (intern var-name package)))
    (proclaim `(special ,var))
    (push var *global-list*)))
```

Please see

- [`proclaim`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_procla.htm)
- [`intern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm)
- [`*package*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pkg.htm)

Alternatively, you can use a macro as the other answer suggests - in
fact, symbol creation at macroexpansion time (which is part of
compilation) is a *very* common thing,
cf. [`gensym`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_gensym.htm).

## Your problem

There is little reason to do this though.

Global variables created at run time were not available at compile time
and are, therefore, pretty useless.

[***Why do you want to do this?***](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/215439)

If you want to map strings to values, you are much better off using an
`equal` [hash table](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/18_.htm).

If you want to integrate with [`read`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_rd.htm),
you should call it while binding
[`*package*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pkg.htm)
to your internal temp package and then use
[`symbol-value`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_symb_5.htm)
to store and retrieve values.
You will use [`intern`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm) to
map "variable names" to the symbols.

Comment: Thank you. I will study this approach. I am looking into ways to allow the code to modify itself, or at least part of itself will change it next time it loads. I am new to Lisp and I can see its power in doing things like this. I don't have any application in mind :)

Comment: Please note that self-modifying code is a pretty non-trivial stuff and usually you can accomplish what you want without such arcana. You might want to discuss your specific issues.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with a macro:

```
(defvar *global-list* nil)
```

I changed `global-name` so that it also accepts symbols, to avoid thinking about whether the string should be upcased or not. With a symbol, the case is given by `readtable-case` (you can use uninterned symbols if you want to avoid polluting packages).

```
(defun global-name (name)
  (check-type name (or string symbol))
  (intern
    (concatenate 'string "*" (string name) "*")))
```

I named the macro `defvar*`:

```
(defmacro defvar* (name)
  `(push
    (defvar ,(global-name name) ',name)
    *global-list*))
```

Tests:

```
CL-USER> (defvar* #:foo)
(*FOO*)
CL-USER> (defvar* #:bar)
(*BAR* *FOO*)
```

Note:

You can also add an optional package argument like in @sds's answer, that's better.

Answer (score 2):

This is [most likely a XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) since it's very unusual to need to make a variable with a name made up in runtime. It's very common in compile time, but not runtime. @coredump has already covered compile time macros if that is what you are after.

Here is how you do it though:

```
(defun add-global-var (var)
  "defvars a global variable and adds it to *global-list*"
  (let ((var-name  (intern (string-upcase (global-name var)))))
    (set var-name var)
    (push var-name *global-list*)))
```

`set` is deprecated, but I doubt it will ever be removed. Implementations might not be able to run as fast though since this is like messing with internals.

Since the names are not from source you you have no good use for the bidnings. because of this I would rather use a hash:

```
(defvar *bindings* (make-hash-table :test #'eq))
(defun add-binding (var)
  (let ((var-name (intern (string-upcase (global-name var)))))
    (setf (gethash var-name *bindings*) var)
    *bindings*))
```

A reason to do this is as a part of your own little interpreter symbol table or something. You don't need a list of them since you can get all the keys from the hash as well as get the bound values.

Comment: Nice answer. It may appear to be XY problem. However, being able to see how such a task is done gives a deep insight into how clisp works. The focus for me is on how to use defvar (or similar) dynamically  rather than how to create global variables.

Comment: @Makketronix I suggest you start by reading [The roots of LISP](http://www.paulgraham.com/rootsoflisp.html). Also CLISP is one implementation of Common Lisp and not the language itself. Being [a standard](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Front/index.htm) it has [many implementations](http://www.cliki.net/Common+Lisp+implementation).